# MVC with multiple data sources scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Well, I'm developing an app using MVC Pattern, but I found MVC is used only for one scenario:
MVC is strongly dependent of an only database connection at once to follow up correctly the pattern.

But I have these different data sources:

Oracle Server (Only reading data source) (ERP)
Sql Server (Loggin database, only reading) (Human Resources)
XML (Local Dabase) Write, read and updating.

Is it possible to follow the MVC pattern properly in this scenario?

If it is possible, what I have to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure - MVC is completely agnostic of the data source.  Simple templates and wizards may only connect to one source but if you separate concerns (repositories, etc.) properly there's no reason why you can't have multiple data sources.

Comment: Google 'C# Repository pattern'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC is a UI pattern. It's purpose is to organize your UI layer and not the whole system. Consider using other patterns for the data access layer. In MVC a Controller is responsible for constructing Models and gluing them to Views. How that construction occurs is not under the scope of MVC. Call an external data access library, a service, use a repository etc. are all valid choices and they don't interfere with the MVC pattern at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, it's possible.

M in MVC means a model, i.e. any significant class of **domain**. You wrote about a different level, the level of **data access**. It's possible that domain classes are loaded from different sources at the same time. Although this solution can't be called perfect, however, it often occurs in the real world.

Judging by what you've written, you use the low-level data access classes as models. So often make small applications. However, the larger application requires implicit separation of models and data access objects.

Comment: Yes (I am newie), I will create a  web service to feed my XML database and increase it, just to follow the pattern. More work, too much, cause if i add a DAL, this pattern will be affected, cause MVC doesnt provides another option, or if you know another option, i will appreciate your advice. Thanks.

Comment: M in MVC means ViewModel, you have to write a ViewModel tailored for the View. You shouldn't use directly a domain object in your View or as input of a Controller.

Comment: @Guillaume It depends. MVVM is recent pattern compared to MVC.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko I'm just saying that your Model in ASP MVC shouldn't be domain classes but Model class specific to your Views (that's why I call tem ViewModel). That's not a full ViewModel as you might see in MVVM : it doesn't exposes actions, actions remains in Controller, no observable, no real time binding...